# Verifying COM Serialized data packet using WinDbg

Tags: debugging, windbg

I was trying to verify COM packet structure (Serialized data packet) using WinDbg in one of my windows application which uses COM for out of process communication.

What I know that call format of GetHGlobalFromStream() function is this [Reference](https://github.com/kimgr/cogetserverpid/blob/master/cogetserverpid.h).

```
hr = ::GetHGlobalFromStream(pMarshalStream, &rhglobal);
```

During marshaling, after this call is successful **rhglobal** should be pointing the current memory handle used by the specified stream object and it should point to the Serialized data packet (starting with MEOW header).

So to verify that with WinDbg, I did this

```
1. bp combase!GetHGlobalFromStream  ; set break point at GetHGlobalFromStream
2. r $t1 = poi(esp+8); t1 is holding the address of rhglobal; 2nd arg.
3. db $t1;  dump bytes at address t1 (rhglobal) before call completed.
4. gu;      Step out of GetHGlobalFromStream() function
5. db $t1; Here we are back to callee; So we again tring to dump content of t1 (rhglobal).
```

But in last line, I think I should see the OBJ_HEADER's first few bytes "**MEOW**". But I don't see that.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? If its not the right way to see the Packet, how can I see that using debugger?

Comment: What you linked to isn't a reference, but a sample doing, it seems, something completely different to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Msdn reference for the api https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379145(v=vs.85).aspx has a caveat about globalrealloc see if thats what is happening